# How do I access a value?

Tags: python, json

I have this:

```
list = {"keywords": [{"name": "sam", "age": "21", "job": "engineer"}]}
```

How would I access the `age` and assert it like, the age must be 21:         `self.assertEqual(list["keywords"]['age'], "21")`
I know that assert is wrong, but that's my attempt, so please help me understand.

Comment: `data["keywords"][0]["age"]`. `[0]` because you dict is into a list (of 1 element)

Comment: Is your list named `list` or `data`?  Other than that, yea what @Corralien said above.

Comment: You really shouldnt replace keywords such as `list` and on top of that your data isn't even a `list` it's a `dict`

Answer (score 2):

You can access `age` this way

```
list = {"keywords": [{"name": "sam", "age": "21", "job": "engineer"}]}
print(list['keywords'][0]['age'])
```

prints

```
21
```

However, the `list` variable is in fact a dictionary, which may cause confusion.

Answer (score 1):

You are Close!
If you see, data["keywords"] is a list, and then a dict inside the first element of that list.

You will want data["keywords"][0]["age"]